# Particles in Free Fields

Tags: intuition, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory

For the state $\left|\vec{p}\right> = a_{\vec{p}}^{\dagger}\left|0\right>$ we have the energy

$H\left|\vec{p}\right>=E_{\vec{p}}\left|\vec{p}\right>$  $\space\space\space\space\space\space\space$         (1)

with the usual commutation relations $\left[H,a_{\vec{p}}^{\dagger}\right]=E_{\vec{p}}a_{\vec{p}}^{\dagger}$ etc.

The classical total momentum $\vec{P}$ acts on $\left|\vec{p}\right>$ as

$\vec{P}\left|\vec{p}\right>=\vec{p}\left|\vec{p}\right>$.    $\space\space\space\space\space\space\space$   (2)

My problem is both intuition and calculation. Other than the words total, state and 3-momentum respectively, what is the intuitive idea\difference behind $\vec{P}$, $\left|\vec{p}\right>$ and $\vec{p}$? As in, what does equation (2) tell us physically? In fact, how has equation (2) been derived using the integral equation of $\vec{P}$?

Comment: About $1^{st}$ question, $H\left|0\right> = 0$. About $2^{nd}$ question, $\vec{P}$ is an observable, a physical quantity one make measurement. $\vec{p}$ is one of its possible value and $\left|\vec{p}\right>$ is a pure state where measurement of the observable $\vec{P}$ always return the value $\vec{p}$. You don't derive equation $(2)$, it is the definition of $\left|\vec{p}\right>$.

Comment: Ok that's answered my first question which was actually very simple. So equation (2) is just a definition? Surely you can deduce it using the integral equation for $\vec{P}$?

Comment: It is actually the other way around, you have the definition of $\left|\vec{p}\right>$, so you can use your choice of $\vec{P}$ to work out the coordinate representation of $\left|\vec{p}\right>$ (i.e. $\left<\vec{x}\mid\vec{p}\right> \propto e^{i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}}$).

Comment: Your state $\vert\vec{p}\rangle$ is a state with a single particle of momentum $\vec{p}.$  If you measure the momentum of this state, which is what applying $\vec{P}$ does, the result will be $\vec{p}.$  If you were to apply $\vec{P}$ to a multi-particle state, the result would be the sum of the momenta of the particles in the state.  The notation "$\vert\vec{p}\rangle$" follows the quantum mechanics convention of labeling eigenvectors of a set of commuting observables by the eigenvalues of those observables.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\mathrm A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix. An eigenvalue of $\mathrm A$ is a scalar $\lambda$ such that there exists a non-zero vector $v$ satisfying

$$ \mathrm A v = \lambda v.$$

Now, as you study Physics, we'll do some abuse of notation and i'll call

- $a$ my eigenvalue $\lambda$;
- $\left|a\right\rangle$ my eigenvector $v$ associated to $a$.

Now my equation goes like this

$$ A \left|a\right\rangle = a \left|a \right\rangle.$$

The nice thing with this notation is that you keep the information of which eigenvalue $v$ is associated to.

There is no more than notations here…